# How to pass string to a makefile from shell script?

Tags: shell, makefile

I tried in the following way

In shell script :

```
Var='abc xyz' make one myvar=$Var
```

But when it goes into makefile it is just showing `myvar` as `abc` but it is not taking `abc xyz` as my input

Answer (score 0):

> `Var='abc xyz' make one myvar=$Var`

First of all, when expanding the `Var` variable in the line above, you *may be* expanding an *undefined variable* (i.e.: `Var`). What the line above is doing is just passing an environment variable called `Var` with that value to the process which is going to run `make`.

For the same reason, the following line **may not** print "Hello World" unless `Var` was previously defined with that value:

```
Var='Hello World' echo $Var
```

The following line will however display "Hello World":

```
Var='Hello World'; echo $Var
```

`$Var` in those examples above is being expanded by the shell. The process running `echo` receives the `Var` variable, not the shell.

---

#### Back to the main problem

> But when it goes into makefile it is just showing `myvar` as abc but it is not taking abc xyz as my input

The line

```
Var='abc xyz'; make one myvar=$Var
```

is being expanded by the shell as:

```
Var='abc xyz'; make one myvar=abc xyz
```

The space above is used as separator for command-line arguments, so the process running `make` is actually receiving two arguments instead of one in place of the command-line variable:

1. `myvar=abc`
2. `xyz`

#### Solution

You need to scape the space, so that it won't be interpreted as an argument separator by the shell. You can achieve that by placing double quotes around `$Var`:

```
Var='abc xyz'; make one myvar="$Var"
```

This way, the process running `make` will receive a single argument for the command-line variable: `myvar=abc xyz`.

Comment: As you explained at the beginning of your answer, unless `Var` is already defined, `Var='abc xyz' make one myvar="$Var"` will not do what the OP wants. Use `Var='abc xyz'; make one myvar="$Var"`, instead.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks for the tip. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't just pass it through the environment?  E.g.,

```
.PHONY: all
all: DEBUG

.PHONY: DEBUG
DEBUG:
        @echo $(test)
```

yields

```
$ test="this is a test" make DEBUG
this is a test
```